# Rails delayed_job - how can I make sure there is workers running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

If I forget to start delayed_job workers on server, the delay jobs will always pending and seems I can't get any errors from Delayed::Job API. is there any easy way to debug with this mistake? I have a dashboard to list the failed background jobs for admins, it could be great to have an alert if there is no worker running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I can find a empty job with Delayed::Job in this case, and it will continue if the worker working again, so I think it should be fine.